# How to let my overflow div scroll always at bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used

```
$('.chatroom-upper-container').scrollTop($('.chatroom-upper-container')[0].scrollHeight);
```

it only work when i send a new message the scroll will update to bottom but how do when load the page the div scroll will always go down?

https://jsfiddle.net/729jz8me/

Everthing is work fine in JsFiddle

but in my page the scroll wont go to bottom when loaded the page
here is my page
[image]

the scroll will go down when i send a new message so how do i make the page loaded the scroll will go to bottom?

**EDIT**
Maybe i didn't state the question very clearly. So what i want is when i open the page the scroll will be at the bottom.
Now I can go to bottom of the page when i send new message but when i close it reopen again the scroll of the page will be top again. I no sure why my code didn't work on page only work in JsFiddle

Comment: make some delay on jquery code...

Comment: use setTimeout jquery function, It will solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try following jQuery code :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('.chatroom-upper-container').scrollTop($('.chatroom-upper-container')[0].scrollHeight);
   }, 500);
});
```

It may help you.

Comment: it didn't slove the problem.When open the page the scroll is always on top== i really don't know why it cant on bottom when i open the page

Comment: can you give me your URL of that page?

Comment: This link may solved your problem, the link is for top to bottom but it gives you idea, Otherwise give me URL I will solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

We can combine my idea with yours:

- Start the list at the bottom with your code
- Create a button to trigger an event, when the user click the button, the scroll get to the bottom.

So, thus when we started the page the first time, the list will be at the bottom, then when you send a message the list will be in bottom too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //When page is loaded the first time
   $('.chatroom-upper-container').scrollTop($('.chatroom-upper-container')[0].scrollHeight);
   //Thus when page is loaded, the list started at the top 
   $('.YourSendButton').click(function(){
       $('.chatroom-upper-container').scrollTop($('.chatroom-upper-container')[0].scrollHeight);
   });  
});
```

Comment: I want is when i open the page the scroll will at the bottom. i can send new message the scroll will be bottom but when i close the page reopen it again the scroll of the page will be top again